# NodeJS REST API Backend hostet on Heroku crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, heroku

I have provided my Backend Code to Heroku. It is a REST API written with NodeJS - ExpressJS.

Heroku starts up and runs my server successfully, but when I for example want to make a request to my backend with the new url that my server is hostet I get a error:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET
```

I am trying to make the request via Postman to test if something is working for that I just changed the url to the new url and kept my api routes call so I changed from this:

```
https://192.xxx.50.xx:6969/api/hours/daydata/2020-08-05/138
```

to this:

```
https://myapp-xapp.herokuapp.com/api/hours/daydata/2020-08-05/138
```

should this generally work or is this wrong? I thought that now I can fetch against this new URL like I did with my PC IP address while developing locally.

I am new to heroku help would be appreciated.

Comment: first, you should use Heroku URL, Second is your app successfully running on Heroku? type below from your application folder and share, heroku logs --tail

Comment: yeah i think the whole problem is some intern stuff in my company thats why it cant connect to my db and hence the timeout